# what is (__ASSERT_VOID_CAST (0))?

Tags: c, macros

From assert.h file in C:

```
#define assert(expr)        (__ASSERT_VOID_CAST (0))
```

I wonder what is (__ASSERT_VOID_CAST (0))? I try to find its implementation but could not find anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

Well, `__ASSERT_VOID_CAST` will be another macro somewhere, and when asserts are 'turned off' it will expand to something equivalent with

```
((void) 0)
```

which is a way to get a `void` expression. In older implementations `assert()` just expanded to an empty string, but a void-expression will let you use the comma-operator to wriggle it into an expression, like:

```
while(assert(n > 0), k/n > 10) { ... }
```

Comment: Wouldn't a simple 0, without the void cast, work as well there?

Comment: A simple `0;` gives 'warning: statement with no effect' when used as a statement. So it might work for the `while` fragment, it won't do for the more common use of `assert()` as a statement.

Comment: @Thomas - yes it would.  but remember that the `assert()` macro is defined as being a void expression. So having it expand to a simple `0` would be incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

In the assert.h on my particular system it says:

```
#if defined __cplusplus && __GNUC_PREREQ (2,95)
# define __ASSERT_VOID_CAST static_cast<void>
#else
# define __ASSERT_VOID_CAST (void)
#endif
```

So it's a cast to void, and the reason to use it is to avoid warnings about unsed values when NDEBUG is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

From `assert.h`, a few lines above the definition of `assert` (linux, kubuntu):

```
#if defined __cplusplus && __GNUC_PREREQ (2,95)
# define __ASSERT_VOID_CAST static_cast<void>
#else
# define __ASSERT_VOID_CAST (void)
#endif
```